# Optimize ListView.builder children rebuilds with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Im working on a live chat application using riverpod as my state management solution and wanted to know if there was a way to avoid rebuilding all the ListView elements everytime the widget is rebuilt.
This is the current code for the widget itself:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final chatController = ref.watch(chatControllerProvider);

    return chatController.when(
      data: (messages) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messages.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              return const SizedBox(height: 40);
            }
            return ChatMessageCard(
              message: messages[index - 1],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      error: (e, s) => Text('Error: $e'),
      loading: () => Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
```

Here is the code for the controllerProvider:

```dart
class ChatController extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<List<Message>> {
  Future<List<Message>> _fetchMessages() async {
    final resultEither = await ref.read(chatRepositoryProvider).getMessages();

    return resultEither
        .getOrElse((failure) => throw Exception(failure.toString()));
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Message>> build() async {
    return _fetchMessages();
  }

  Future<void> addMessage(String message) async {
    final currentMessages = state;

    final resultEither =
        await ref.read(chatRepositoryProvider).sendMessage(message);

    state = resultEither.fold(
      (l) => AsyncValue.error(l.toString(), StackTrace.current),
      (r) => AsyncValue.data([...currentMessages.value!, r]),
    );
  }


}
```

The thing is every time I add a new message the widget is rebuild as it should because of the state change, and all the message cards are rebuilt as well.

I want to have rebuild only the new chat messages widgets, but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: That's not true. There are various examples in Riverpod's repo that correctly handle listview updates. Both the [todos](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/main.dart), the [StackOverflow](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/stackoverflow/lib/home.dart) and the [Marvel](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/marvel/lib/src/screens/home.dart) apps implement a ListView screen which only rebuild what's needed on updates (refreshes/mutations)

Comment: Thanks Remi, I was waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `ListView.builder` it seems impossible. The only thing you can try is to use a normal `ListView` and track the index in each `ChatMessageCard()` widget using the `select()` method.

In any case, only the visible widgets will be rebuilt, not the entire list, if you use `ListView.builder`.

Comment: But in this case wouldn't the cards still be rebuilt when adding a new element to the messages list?